# excel macro cells.find won't use variable for some reason

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard

I have this code as an excel macro.

```
  Dim MyData As DataObject
  Set MyData = New DataObject
  MyData.GetFromClipboard

  MsgBox MyData.GetText

  On Error GoTo NotFound
  Cells.Find(What:=MyData.GetText, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
  :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
  False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

  NotFound:
```

**`MsgBox` writes the value correctly, but the `What:=MyData.GetText` just won't work. Why? Or, more importantly, how to fix it?**

If it is not clear, I am trying to find the next value equal to the one in clipboard at the moment. I have referenced the MSForms so that is not the problem.

If I assign MyData.GetText to a variable and use the variable, the same happens, `MsgBox` works, BUT `What:=myvariable` doesn't.

Comment: what do you Dim `myVariable` as? If you don't use `String`, try that. You may need to wrap `MyData.GetText` in `Cstr`

Comment: when you say it `just won't work` what do you mean? Do you get an error message? Or it's just not finding what you want?

Comment: not finding it. if i remove the `On Error...` it throws the error 91 (basically not found). if i replace `what:=` as `what:="TEXT"` it does work and it finds TEXT. if TEXT was in clipboard and i read it with above, it just fails to find it.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why this works, but it does:

```
Sub test()
Dim MyData As DataObject
Dim rng As Excel.Range

Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.GetFromClipboard
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=MyData.GetText, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
                                 :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                                 False, SearchFormat:=False)

rng.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe bc you explicitly reference the sheet object?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, no that's not it, that's just force of habit :). It still works without it, and with the reference it doesn't work without the `rng` variable I added.

Comment: VBA is pretty nutty sometimes, I've found, or so it seems. +1 for checking this out and finding a solution.

Comment: I was just look at this some more on a different computer and the originally posted code works fine. I'm running Excel 2010 on both computers, with Win XP on the one where @b0x0rz's code failed and Win 7 on this one where it worked.